# How to get 24h support for a Joomla site?

Tags: commercial

This could sound like a strange question, so let me explain why I need a 24h assistance service for a Joomla site. I've created a website for a customer, using many extensions (EasySocial, Community Surveys, Quick2cart, etc.). I've done this in my spare time and I'm not always reachable by my customer due to circumstances related to my work.

The customer is aware of this and it's fine for him to wait weeks for a change in the site, for a new feature request and for planned maintenance. But, if there's suddendly something unexpected with the website (which is commercial), to whom could he call? So, I'm asking if there's someone who gives as a service (at payment, of course) a 24h remote assistance, for a little annual fee or also hourly payed.

Is there something similar to my description in the Joomla world?

Comment: [Joomlancers](http://www.joomlancers.com/) or [Stackoverflow Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs)? Seeing as it's 24 hour remote assistance, it **may** not be that cheap.

Comment: By putting these two terms in one sentence _'a 24h remote assistance, for a little annual fee'_, you have created great oxymoron, my freind... Good luck in finding it though... Please report back here when you find such a thing.

Comment: I was going to suggest you contact me until I saw that you were in Italy. Heh, it's best if you find someone local to your client so they sleep when your client sleeps. Find a good joomla site builder who could be on call at least. If it was me though, and they wanted 24 hour support, that monthly fee might not be big, but my hourly rate would be ON TOP of it, and it wouldn't be low if it was in the middle of the night.

Comment: @MirkoMikan the "little" has not been detailed... Of course it would be appropriate to the duty. Moreover, the annual fee is just for the grant of the service. The hours spent fixing problems would be payed separately... It's not so unfair, I think...

Comment: @ufo - Thanks for clarification, now I see what you ment. I am also supporting sites of my clients that I have built, but no one ever suggested need for 24 hour availability of my services, and I bill them per monthly service contract. As Brian suggested, I would also ask for big hourly rate if someone wants me to work in 3AM. Dunno what to suggest to you...

Answer (score 1):

We have offered this service in the past and I wanted to share how we did it in case someone else wanted to do it for you.  We setup rules in our MacMail that if an email was received from a certain client (or you can do something specific in subject like 911), it would forward the email to our IFTTT account.  We had a rule there that would send a text message to a member on our team which would wake up them up so they could work on it.  Usually that person was someone that was looking for extra hours/projects, etc.